# What is the `_base` property of an ReverseRandomAccessCollection?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

Is it good practice to use the `_base` property to access the elements of a `ReverseRandomAccessCollection`?

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3]
print(myArray.first) // returns 1

print(myArray.reversed().first) // returns 3
print(myArray.reversed()._base.first) // return 1, which is the underlying base array
```

Comment: I get different results: `myReversedArray.first` returns 3 and `myReversedArray._base.first` returns 1. Be very careful when using any property or method that begins with an underscore (`_`). These are undocumented and meant for the compiler

Comment: why would `myReversedArray.first` return 1 when you initialised it with reversed version of `myArray`?

Comment: Sorry guys, had a typo, I updated the code.

Comment: i got same results : `1 3 1`

Comment: Getting 1-3-1 copying and pasting your own code. Are you sure you run the exact same as you are showing here? What version of Swift?

Comment: I must have mixed it up... my mistake. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ReverseRandomAccessCollection` (you can see [its full implementation here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift#L188)) is a simply a wrapper that presents a reversed *view* onto an underlying `RandomAccessCollection` (this saves from having to do an O(n) walk through it).

The way this is achieved is through keeping an `_base` property of the underlying collection, and then implementing the `RandomAccessCollection` protocol in order to present a reversed view onto it, such reversing index traversal (comments mine):

```
public struct ReversedRandomAccessCollection<
  Base : RandomAccessCollection
> : RandomAccessCollection {

    public let _base: Base // the underlying collection to present the reversed view on

    // ...

    public var startIndex: Index { // startIndex accesses endIndex of _base
        return ReversedRandomAccessIndex(_base.endIndex)
    }

    public var endIndex: Index { // endIndex accesses startIndex of _base
        return ReversedRandomAccessIndex(_base.startIndex)
    }

    public func index(after i: Index) -> Index { // index(after:) gets the index(before:)
        return ReversedRandomAccessIndex(_base.index(before: i.base))
    }

    public func index(before i: Index) -> Index { // index(before:) gets the index(after:)
        return ReversedRandomAccessIndex(_base.index(after: i.base))
    }

    public func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy n: IndexDistance) -> Index { 
        // index offset is simply made negative,
        // then forwarded to base's index(_:offsetBy:) method
        return ReversedRandomAccessIndex(_base.index(i.base, offsetBy: -n))
    }

    // ...
}
```

As the `_base` property is `public`, there's nothing to stop you from using it. However, underscore prefixed properties and methods are used to indicate implementation details that are not part of the public API – as they're often not designed to be used directly, and are subject to change without warning.

In this case you can simply work with the array before you call `reversed()` – it will be the same as `_base` (until you mutate it). Therefore, instead of doing:

```
myArray.reversed()._base.first
```

you should just do:

```
myArray.first
```

which will yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments better not use `_` methods, there is no need for that risk. In Swift 3 `reversed()` returns wrapper `ReversedRandomAccessCollection` to access array as if it was reversed - *without* the need to allocate new array, while `reverse()` mutates existing array:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3]
myArray.reverse()
print(myArray.first) // returns 3
print(myArray.reversed().first) // returns 1
print(myArray.reversed()._base.first) // return 3
```

Note: you can call `reverse()` on `var` only