# Swift Array reversed() function O(1) complexity?

Tags: arrays, swift, reverse

We can reverse an Array in Swift using reversed function, here's the example:

```
let numbers = [3, 5, 7]
let reversedNumbers = Array(numbers.reversed())
print(reversedNumbers)
// Prints "[7, 5, 3]"
```

Here's the  link :[Array reversed()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed)

At the end of the discussion part, it says **Complexity O(1)**, I believe this is about time complexity, how can reverse an array take O(1) time?

Comment: If you read all the words on that page, you'll notice that `reversed` provides a reversed *view* of the array. It doesn't reverse the array, nor create a new one.

Comment: It returns a `ReversedRandomAccessCollection` which is just a reversed *view* onto the underlying array (compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39547399/2976878). But saying `Array(numbers.reversed())` will create a new array by walking through that view, so is O(n).

Comment: @Hamish,@Molbdnilo Thank you. Got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `reversed()` returns an object with wrapper over the original array not actual reversion of the contents hence `O(1)`.

If you check the return type of `reversed()` call it is `ReversedCollection` which internally keeps original collection as `_base` unless its contents are modified. Basically `ReversedCollection` is just presenting/returning elements of its base collection in the reverse manner to save **time** and **memory**.

Following example shows that reversed array remains same as the original array unless it is modified:

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3]
var reversedArray = originalArray.reversed()

print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray[0])")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray._base[0])")


print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray.first)")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray.first)")

originalArray[0] = 4 // Modification makes a separate copy of each instance
print("0th index of OriginalArray \(originalArray[1])")
print("0th index of ReversedBaseArray \(reversedArray._base[1])")


// Console Output:
// 0th index of OriginalArray 1
// 0th index of ReversedBaseArray 1


// First element of OriginalArray Optional(1)
// First element of ReversedBaseArray Optional(3)


// 0th index of OriginalArray 4
// 0th index of ReversedBaseArray 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that this is not true for direct indexing, which is confusing. If you say `array.reversed()[1]` for example, you lose the efficiency.

Comment: Direct indexing is only for the sake of understanding the underneath concept.

Comment: It's not a critique of the code, it's a sad fact about the method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332664/is-swift-array-reversedn-efficient-or-not where we've just been talking about this. I arrived at your answer in search of help on this issue. I didn't get any. :)